# "se lo quité a mi nieto" vs "se lo lo quité de mi nieto"

Tags: preposiciones

Native Spanish speakers explained to me that "se lo quité a mi nieto" is "I stole this FROM my grandson" and "se lo quité de mi nieto" is incorrect.

How would you say "I stole my grandson" vs "I stole [it] from my grandson"? 
Am I wrong expecting "de" in it somewhere to express "from", and not "a"?

Comment: Thank you for your question, and welcome to [Spanish Language](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Aside from all the grammar @guifa explained on his answer as a native speaker I'd say those sentences like: "Se lo quité/robé a mi nieto" = "I took/stole it from my grandson" and "I stole my grandson" = **"Me robé a mi nieto"** or "le robé/quité mi nieto a sus padres".

Comment: @DGaleano _Robar_ for cildren is the verb we use in Central America, too.

Answer (score 4):

English uses the preposition *de* with words like *take*, *steal*, etc.  But in Spanish, the person who is having something taken from them is just a regular indirect object, and thus uses an *a* when made explicit:

- Robé los dulces *a los niños*.
  *Les* robé los dulces *a los niños*.
  *Les* robé los dulces.

The thing that you actually take is a direct object.  It *normally* doesn't use any preposition when made explicit:

- Quité *los dulces* a los niños.
  *Los dulces*, pues, *los* quité a los niños.
  *Los* quité a los niños.

There is an exception, and that is when the direct object is an person or a person-like entity (pets, etc).  Those require an *a*, but they are still direct objects.

- Secuestré *a Rufus* <sub>(= perro)</sub>.
  *Lo* secuestré.

Now, given that, let's look at your sentence.

- Se lo quité a mi nieto.

Here, we have the construction *se lo* which is, in reality, *le* (=indirect object, or the grandson) and *lo* (=direct object, whatever you took) combined.  So we interpret it as I took a thing (*lo*) from a person (*le* / *a mi nieto*).

You can't have doubled pronouns with verbs in Spanish (it's *theoretically* possible to construct a sentence that would require two or even possible three *se*s, but Spanish collapses them into a single one if it ever happens), so having two *lo*s isn't possible.

To say *I stole my grandson*, you would just say

- *Quité a mi nieto*

Why wouldn't use a pronoun here?  If we did, we would end up with the following

- *Lo quité a mi nieto*

While *technically* correct (with *lo* = *mi nieto*), this sentence will be almost undoubtedly misunderstood as *lo* being distinct from *mi nieto* because of the preposition *a* that normally indicates an indirect object, and *quitar* (and similar) often having both a direct and an indirect object.  If you added in an indirect object, though, the confusion would disappear.

- *Lo quité a mi nieto a su familia*

Because the *lo* can only match up with *nieto*, we know it's the direct object, and thus the family is the indirect object.

Comment: @guifa *Quité a mi nieto* would be *I pushed my grandson aside* or *I unsubscribed my grandson (from some activity)*, but not *I stole my grandson*. *Quitar* is a verb with several meanings, and in most contexts the "steal" interpretation only happens when there's an indirect object specified (compare *?quito un balón* vs *robo un balón*). As you point out, in your last sentence there is an IO, but to be honest it is so convoluted I can barely make any sense out of it.

Comment: @Yay I agree I'd use a different verb. I was trying to keep with the same as the OP's sentence, but I'll probably edit in the morning to point it out (I actually originally typed such a notice out but deleted it to keep the answer specifically to the grammar part)